# How to print out a list with missing numbers?

Tags: python

I have a piece of code that is supposed to print out a list of numbers and also # for every time there is a duplicate number on the list, printing it out should look like this:
list = [6,7,7,9]
6#
7##
8
9#

Here is what i have so far:

```
def print_list(list1):
    list2 = [int(i) for i in list1]
    full_set = [x for x in range(list2[0], list2[-1] + 1)]
    list2.extend(full_set)
    list3 = list(set(list2))
    result = sorted([(x, list2.count(x)) for x in list3], key=lambda y: y[1])
    result.sort()
    for elem in result:
        print("{0:>2}".format(elem[0]), "{}".format(elem[1]*"#"))
```

And it comes out wrong:

6 ##
 7 ###
 8 #
 9 ##

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is the input list sorted?

Comment: Did you tried changing this line `print("{0:>2}".format(elem[0]), "{}".format(elem[1]*"#"))` to `print("{0:>2}".format(elem[0]), "{}".format((elem[1]-1)*"#"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list2.extend(full_set)` adds one extra number for each number in the range. You need to reduce 1 from the count of elements in `result`. You can do it in the list creation

```
result = sorted([(x, list2.count(x) - 1) for x in list3], key=lambda y: y[1])
```

or in the print

```
for elem in result:
    print("{0:>2}".format(elem[0]), "{}".format((elem[1] - 1)*"#"))
```

output

```
6 #
7 ##
8 
9 #
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this works:

```
def print_list(list1):
    list2 = [x for x in range(list1[0], list1[-1] + 1)]
    list3 = list(set(list2))
    result = sorted([(x, list1.count(x)) for x in list3], key=lambda y: y[1])
    result.sort()
    for elem in result:
        print("{0:>2}".format(elem[0]), "{}".format(elem[1]*"#"))

print_list([6,7,7,9])
```

Output:

```
 6 #
 7 ##
 8 
 9 #
```

The issue with your current code is that you add your set of the numbers you're expecting to `list2`, so counting the amount of each number in `list2` yields one more than you expect.

This is what `list2` looks like with your original code:

```
[6, 7, 7, 9, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

This is because your call to the `extend` method takes `list2` ( `[6, 7, 7, 9]` ), and adds `full_set` ( `[6, 7, 8, 9]` ) to it.  Thus when you count the occurrences of each number in `list2`, you are counting the original number, and then an extra one, because you've extended `list2` with `full_set`.